# How to map array to object with Typescript

Tags: typescript

How can I convert this array:

```
['black', 'grey', 'dark grey'];
```

To this:

```
[ MyObject { name: 'black', description: 'colour is black' }, MyObject { ... } ]
```

Comment: What exactly is MyObject? how do you create them?

Comment: You can use `map` 

Answer (score 4):

A first straight forward solution: define an interface `Colour`, create a new array, here: `colours`, and iterate through your old array to push items into your new one:

```
interface Colour {
  name: string;
  description: string;
};

const colours: Colour[] = [];

['black', 'grey', 'dark grey'].forEach((colour: string) => {
  colours.push({
    name: colour,
    description: `colour is ${colour}`
  });
});
```

Using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```
const colours: Colour[] = ['black', 'grey', 'dark grey'].map(colour => {
  return {
    name: colour,
    description: `colour is ${colour}`
  };
});
```

Answer (score 3):

**Simple version**

```
['black', 'grey', 'dark grey'].map((color) => { return {name: color, description: `colour is ${color}`}});
```

**Best/Better practice**

```
interface Color {
  name: string;
  description: string;
}

type Colors = Color[];

const colors: string[] = ['black', 'grey', 'dark grey'];

colors.map((colour): Colors => ({ name: colour, description: `colour is ${colour}` }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another straight forward method using a global type declare (global declaration helps you use it anywhere in the entire project),

```
declare global { // you can still define type without declaring it globally
  type Dictionary<T> = { [key: string]: T };
  type DefaultResponse = { 
    success: boolean,
    message: string,
  }
}

interface MyObject { 
    name: string,
    description: string 
  }
```

and in your function,

```
  var items = ['black', 'grey', 'dark grey']
  var results:[Dictionary<MyObject> | []]  = []

  items.reduce((result, field, index) => { 
    var _obj:Dictionary<string| any> =  { name: field , description : `The colour is ${field}` }
    results.push(_obj)
    return result;
  }, {})

  console.log(results)
```

view it in playground action:
[PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-2WyV2536j3sH3q5AWxoWnuMCc4GUKxjQLAEKwYdKyJrOOYyEQANK+KoO3UnH1O4jjJIQqBQRgvz8WkzCtRlrGZFY1g5LkeRhflSzA31zmXFx+zDCMoy+cFoX7Us3w-CYfz-cUvylWV2FoVo-AdRVPSIVjGFYdVGC1LjWEA4DS30MCi3NS0AWtW0BHtbinW0dxXR2boPWTH1sj9AMmBDBMcP9S5IgCBMk1VVN01bI4mIQVoYRZNZRXgSA+GQRhpWsnYVHEndDR0KRIK-XN80LM0fN88tK3ADzWlrQ0GzcZtSwi2BmH81yv1i+5zyeYAXhYcMfj+ZcKCkKhDh0Pcu0PPsh1HDdVzmXAuC6KCEAggAvL8V3qnr1y3MKjW+Si1i6vl4QgviUXG7gyCxWFcEaLo5txWB8XRMgyEYObWhQdBn1YFUxDwYkWjA6z8hIFxr1gW8vjIB8n2lcBhs-Eh1UhU8LzyKre3cwgLpbIA)

PS:  If you'll use this frequently for more array with different keys, here's the more generalized solution:

```
 const destructureArray = (expectedKeys:any) => { 
    var aligned:[Dictionary<MyObject> | []]  = []
    var description = "The colour is "
    expectedKeys.reduce((param:any, field:any, index:any) => { 
        var _obj:Dictionary<string| any> =  {  name: field, description: `${description}: ${field}` }
        param = Object.assign(param, _obj)
        aligned.push(_obj)
       return param;
    }, {})
    return aligned;
   }
```

and the function call,

```
var expected = ['black', 'grey', 'dark grey']
var parsed = destructureArray( expected)
console.log(parsed)
```